# c++ windows, compile with mingw as static library and include in visual studio c++ project

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, mingw

c++, windows (in my case windows phone 8, arm & x86 for emulator). I've compiled boost libraries with mingw. as a result I have such files for ex "libboost_random-mgw48-mt-sd-1_53.a".

Is there any possibility to include this static library in visual studio c++ project? Maybe compile with special options... or convert this ".a" file to a visual studio compatible ".lib" file.

I've tried to rename .. but I receive some 'undefined reference' errors.. so they're not directly compatible.

please note that this library (boost) cannot be compiled with visual studio. I've an open question that still has no answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23831050/compile-boost-as-static-library-for-windows-phone-8-arm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the g++ object files with visual c++. However, you can use all the *header only* modules of boost without building anything. For the rest, such as Boost filesystem, build it with visual c++ for use with visual c++.

---

Re

> “please note that this library (boost) cannot be compiled with visual studio”

that's incorrect.

Comment: If boost can be built for windows phone arm with VS please let me know how.

Comment: I looked at your earlier question about it. An ".rsp" file is a Visual C++ *response file*, it specifies compiler command line arguments. Check out why it's being invoked on its own instead of used properly (I think the syntax was like `cl @somefile.rsp`).

Comment: yes, that means that something is wrong with boost compilation scripts and they can't compile with VS for windows phone arm. I have tried with VS2012 & VS2013... windows phone 8 & 8.1 SDKs are installed.

Comment: uhm, take a look at (http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/winrt-support-Adding-support-for-Windows-8-store-phone-to-Boost-libraries-td4661713.html). it's from april 2013. also see (http://boost.2283326.n4.nabble.com/How-to-build-boost-for-ARM-to-use-on-Windows-Phone-td4662579.html#a4662978) from may 2014

Comment: did i say 2013. i meant 2014. argh.